# Placing existing source files into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to put a project in eclipse.
It has a directory structure of "org.project.file"
How can I put the source files into eclipse and maintain directory/path structure.

The package used in the source code is org.project.file
"package org.project.file"
On the file system its

- org

  - project

    - file

I cannot make eclipse keep the directory structure. When I put it in eclipse it unpacks everything in project explorer
and all the imports get messed up (red squiggly lines everywhere)
I do not want to have to create all the packages individually in project explorer and then manually copy every file on the file system.

Comment: Any reason you're not using Import > Existing Project

Answer (score 0):

First you must create a directory (src) in your project where you will put your sources (full path : org.project...).

After that you have to right click your project, select the properties menu then a new window will open.

In that window select 'Java Build Path' then the 'Source' tag, there you have to click the 'Add Folder' button then select the directory you created first (src) and it's done.